# Instancia de UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo una pequeña duda, se puede instanciar de alguna forma (o algo), para llamar a un Panel, updatePanel, div de una página maestra desde otra pagina normal?

Me explico un poco: en la pag maestra tengo un updatePanel (dentro de un panel) con un pequeño form de login, y quisiera llamarlo desde cualquier otra pagina de mi sitio.

Estoy trabajando con asp.net c# webForms.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor mira en la ayuda [ask] , [qué puedo preguntar](/help/on-topic) y [qué no](/help/dont-ask). La pregunta tal cual la tienes ahora es muy amplia y es probable que sea cerrada. Te sugiero que la borres y cuando tengas una pregunta clara lo hagas con [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

No me queda muy clara la pregunta, pero dependiendo como estructures tu página master, puedes utilizarla para que las otras páginas tengan el mismo aspecto de ésta. Si colocas un form en la master, este se mostrará en las demás páginas.

Puedes indicar cuál es la master en las demás páginas en el archivo .aspx de cada una, al principio, mediante directivas, por ejemplo:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MiMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MiPagina.aspx.cs" Inherits="MiProyecto.MiPagina" %>
```

Sin embargo, no se puede acceder a los controles, forms, etc, de la master desde las demás páginas en sus archivos .cs, el código asociado a tu form de login en la master se ejecutará en su archivo .cs, no en el de las páginas que la tienen como master.

Si lo que quieres es poder invocar el login cuando se termina la sesión, por ejemplo, puedes crear una página de login que no herede de la master, personalizarla a tu gusto e invocarla cada vez que detectes que la sesión de un usuario ha terminado, y dejar la master para menús, banners, imagenes de fondo, etc.

Si lo que quieres es utilizar si o si los controles de tu login en todas las páginas, puedes crear un control web personalizado, agregarlo a tu proyecto y así poder llamarlo en tus páginas, por ejemplo:

```
<aspSample:ControlLogin ID="MiControlLogin" runat="server"></aspSample:ControlLogin>
```

Sin embargo, la lógica de comunicación con el servidor de base de datos, etc, se debe manejar para cada una de las páginas donde se utilice.

Comment: Lo que quería era invocar al Login desde cualquiera de las demás páginas, pero entiendo que no se pueda, asique tendré que hacerlo de otra forma. Ahora, otra consulta, los botones de la master tampoco se pueden utilizar desde las otras paginas? Porque tengo el boton de login que se oculta, uno de Logout y un label de bienvenida que se muestran cuando se inicia sesion.. Cómo podría hacer para realizar esas acciones desde todas las paginas? Gracias por tu ayuda !

Comment: SI se pueden utilizar desde otras páginas, por ejemplo, yo tengo una etiqueta con el usuario conectado, la hora y un botón de logout, en la master, y estos controles los muestro y los puedo utilizar en cualquiera de las páginas que hagan referencia a la master. A lo que me referia que no se pueden utilizar, es a invocarlos como objetos desde el archivo .cs de las demás páginas.

Comment: Y cómo lo haces? Porque estuve intentando y no me reconoce los botones, me dice que no existe en el contexto..

Comment: Lo mejor sería que hagas una nueva pregunta, publiques el código de tu master, de tu página y el error o problema, así te podemos ayudar de manera más directa.